# Run Hook file with SequenceSteps in SpecFlow

Tags: c#, automated-tests, bdd, specflow

I'am trying to write simple test in SpecFlow and TestStackWhite, I have created Hook file to save there my BeforeScenario and AfterScenario definitions. Problem is that, when I try to run my test it fails. When I move code section BeforeScenario from Hook file into my TestSequenceSteps.cs `[Given(@"I have opened Test")]` everything is fine.
How can I correctly reference to Hook file?

TestSequence.feature

```
Feature: TestSequence
    Run full Test
    as a test sequence

@run
Scenario: Run test sequence in Test
    Given I have opened Test
    When I press Test button
    And  I press Continue button
    Then test sequnce is run
```

Hooks1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using TestStack.White;
using TestStack.White.Factory;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems;

namespace Test.Steps
{

    [Binding]
    public sealed class Hooks1
    {
        public static Window window;
        public static Application application;

        [BeforeScenario("run")]
        public void BeforeScenario()
        {
            application = Application.AttachOrLaunch(new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tests\\" +
            "directory\\Test.exe"));
            window = application.GetWindow
                (SearchCriteria.ByClassName("TGUI"), InitializeOption.NoCache);
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void AfterScenario()
        {
            window.Close();
        }
    }
```

TestSequenceSteps.cs

```
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using TestStack.White;
using TestStack.White.UIItems;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders;
using NUnit.Framework;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.TabItems;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using TestStack.White.Factory;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test.StepDefinitions
{

    [Binding]
    public class TestSequenceSteps
    {
        private static Window window;
        private static Application application;

        [Given(@"I have opened Test")]
        public void GivenIHaveOpenedTest()
        {

        }

        [When(@"I press Test button")]
        public void WhenIPressTestButton()
        {
            var button = window.Get<Button>(SearchCriteria.ByClassName("TButton"));
            button.Click();
        }

        [When(@"I press Continue button")]
        public void WhenIPressContinueButton()
        {
            var button = window.Get<Button>(SearchCriteria.ByText("ContinueButton"));
            Thread.Sleep(700);
            button.Click();
        }

        [Then(@"test sequnce is run")]
        public void ThenTestSequnceIsRun()
        {
            //ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It cannot find the button, here is the error `When I press Test button
-> error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` But my application is open correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the NullRef exception from accessing the window field in TestSequenceSteps, because this field is never assigned.
You can not share state between your step classes with static fields.

To share this state, I would use Context Injection (http://specflow.org/documentation/Context-Injection/).
With that pattern applied, your code looks then like this:

```
public class SharedState
{
    public Window Window {get;set;}
    public Application Application {get;set;}
}


[Binding]
public class Hooks1
{
    private SharedState _sharedState;

    public Hooks1(SharedState sharedState)
    {
        _sharedState = sharedState;
    }


    [BeforeScenario("run")]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        _sharedState.Application = Application.AttachOrLaunch(new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tests\\directory\\Test.exe"));
        _sharedState.Window = _sharedState.Application.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByClassName("TGUI"), InitializeOption.NoCache);
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void AfterScenario()
    {
        _sharedState.Window.Close();
    }
}

[Binding]
public class TestSequenceSteps
{
    private SharedState _sharedState;

    public TestSequenceSteps(SharedState sharedState)
    {
        _sharedState = sharedState;
    }

    [Given(@"I have opened Test")]
    public void GivenIHaveOpenedTest()
    {

    }

    [When(@"I press Test button")]
    public void WhenIPressTestButton()
    {
        var button = _sharedState.Window.Get<Button>(SearchCriteria.ByClassName("TButton"));
        button.Click();
    }

    [When(@"I press Continue button")]
    public void WhenIPressContinueButton()
    {
        var button = _sharedState.Window.Get<Button>(SearchCriteria.ByText("ContinueButton"));
        Thread.Sleep(700);
        button.Click();
    }

    [Then(@"test sequnce is run")]
    public void ThenTestSequnceIsRun()
    {
        //ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, but what is most important now I see where I did a mistake :)